# Supongamos que + alguien + muere/muera(Indicativo/Subjuntivo)

Tags: selección-de-palabras, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, presente-indicativo

**Indicativo** presente (Tercera persona del singular)

> (1) **Supongamos que** alguien **muere** pero posee un alma inmortal que continua existiendo en otra dimensión.

[Un desafío para la bioética. La cuestión del especismo.](https://books.google.cl/books?id=jizZCE_HB20C&pg=PA542&lpg=PA542&dq=supongamos+que+muere&source=bl&ots=4MrArHL5Oj&sig=ACfU3U2Jx-wY-4X3V522ETdR8l05hpqhOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB_MjCkLX0AhU3FrkGHX0_AowQ6AF6BAgkEAM#v=onepage&q=supongamos%20que%20muere&f=false)

**Subjuntivo** presente (Tercera persona del singular)

> P: ¿Puede aclarar mejor esa diferencia entre posesión diabólica y esclavitud del alma por parte del demonio?

> (2) R: **Supongamos que** un hombre **muera** en estado de posesión diabólica pero en gracia de Dios: ¡Se salva!

[Cara a cara con el demonio](https://books.google.cl/books?id=q9D5cU84frIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Cara+a+cara+con+el+demonio&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Cara%20a%20cara%20con%20el%20demonio&f=false)

¿Hay algo establecido como para elegir automáticamente uno u otro, el indicativo o el subjuntivo?
https://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SGKkKzSHHWkSkXfV

¿O es más bien que, en (2) hay menos posibilidades de que ocurra, en comparación a (1) donde quien habla sí tiene la certeza?

EDIT: Tal vez es porque quien responde en (2) (Francesco Bamonte) es italiano, aunque no me parece inadecuado, de hecho lo he escuchado muchas veces.

Comment: Sin pensarlo demasiado, diria: Supongamos que alguien **murió** o Supongamos que **muera** alguien. El presente no me parece justificable. Se puede imaginar que fulano ya se fue o se imagina que pudiera irse.  ¿No te parece?

Comment: @Lambie 'murió' es Indicativo pretérito perfecto simple vs  Supongamos que haya muerto que sería el subjuntivo pretérito perfecto o el que imperfecto 'que (él) muriera'. Pero la pregunta es si usar el subjuntivo o indicativo, así que no entiendo a que te refieres con que el presente no te parece justificable, eso no está en discusión.

Comment: El presente no me parece posible aqui., Se puede suponer que alguien murió ou que muera o que se haya muerto, o sea que pueda morir, pero no que muer**e**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según E. Ridruejo (*Gramática descriptiva de la lengua española*, §49.4.4), *suponer* como “verbo creador de mundos” permite la alternancia entre subjuntivo e indicativo en las oraciones subordinadas a él, con ciertas condiciones. La elección del modo tiene que ver con la atribución de la verdad del enunciado. La misma puede atribuirse

1. al hablante, o bien
2. al sujeto del verbo principal.

En el caso (1.), el hablante usa el modo indicativo para expresar que se compromete con la verdad del enunciado: *Supongo que ella sabe*.

En el caso (2.), el hablante no se compromete con la veracidad del enunciado y utiliza por lo tanto el subjuntivo, pero esto solo puede ocurrir cuando el verbo principal no es asertivo, es decir, cuando está negado, cuando es una interrogación o cuando expresa un mandato o un deseo: *Supongamos que ella sepa*.

El verbo *suponer* en un enunciado no asertivo también acepta el indicativo, por supuesto (*Supongamos que ella sabe*), pero la diferencia de significado es tan sutil en este caso que Ridruejo considera que está prácticamente neutralizada en este tipo de enunciado.

En mi opinión (ya saliendo de lo que dice Ridruejo), la diferencia no es despreciable en los ejemplos planteados, y sigue la orientación explicada arriba: al decir *Supongamos que alguien muere pero tiene un alma inmortal...*, percibo que el hablante me propone representarme una situación que él considera real; por el contrario *Supongamos que un hombre muera en estado de posesión...* me sugiere que el hablante no cree en la proposición sino que me la propone meramente como hipótesis.

Comment: Perfecto. Porque él tiene experiencia en el tema, no duda de su fe, tal vez ve improbable o inusual que se den todas esas circunstancias, o no son hechos fácilmente constatables.